# Qt MultiLanguage Application

Tags: c++, qt

Basically,I am trying to make a Multi-Language app in Qt. For that, I created `hindi.ts` file and `hindi.qm` file using `lupdate` and `lrelease` commands in `qt 5.10.0 msvsc(2015)` cmd terminal. I have a Language Settings Widget in which I have a combo box and based on the language selected, I load that value into a registry.
As Shown in Below fig 
fig 1 is Structure of My program
fig2 is UI of Language Settings

[1. Block Diagram of  Widgets in my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h23AZ.jpg)

[2. Language Gui Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgdIk.jpg)

**CODE:**

```
void Form_LanguageSettings::on_pbtn_Submit_clicked()
{
    QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MyProject\\Employee", QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.setValue("language", ui->cmb_Language->currentText());

}
```

So, there are no problems while updating.
However, when I want to  retrieve it from the Registry into `ListOfDepartment`  Widget, I retrieve it in this way :

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MyProject\\Employee", QSettings::NativeFormat);

QApplication *app;
QString SelectedLanguage;
SelectedLanguage=settings.value("language").toString();
if(SelectedLanguage.toLower() != "english")
{
    if(SelectedLanguage=="hindi")
    {
        QTranslator translation;

        translation.load("C:/MyProject/LanguagePack/ObjectFiles/HindiDevanagari.qm");
        app->installTranslator(&translation);
    }
}
```

In this way I am unable to load the corresponding language. If I load a particular language manually in `main.cpp` file it loads but if I do it via the settings widgets from my app, it doesn't work. How can I deal with this when the language settings are to be done in a separate widget ? I am new to multilanguage of QT. Please, any help?

Comment: Where do you assign something to that `QApplication *app;` in the second snippet?

Comment: I think it is mandatory to create an object for QApplication and to that object only we can load the translation file ?

Comment: Is there any other method by which i can load the  .qm  file directly

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
QTranslator* translation = new QTranslator();
translation->load("C:/MyProject/LanguagePack/ObjectFiles/HindiDevanagari.qm");
QApplication::instance()->installTranslator(translation);
//or also QApplication::installTranslator(translation), it is static
```

In your code, the `QTranslator` instance is destroyed at the end of the `if` block, and the `app` variable is not assigned

Comment: i tried doing the same way but the language is not changed it still satys in general english. Is it Mandatory to use QApplication Object . Is there any other way to load directly the   translation File.?

Comment: In your code, the app variable is not assigned. You have to create a QApplication instance in the main. You can access to the QApplication global instance using QApplication::instance(). However QApplication::installTranslator() is static, you can use it directy. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Possible you should load your translation using brief file name and QDir e.g.

```
QTranslator * translation =new QTranslator();
QString dir ("C:/MyProject/LanguagePack/ObjectFiles");
translation->load ("HindiDevanagari", dir);
app->installTranslator (translation);
```

Comment: Mr Rusinov i tried with your concept using dir but by that the language pack is not loading at all. that is the language change is not applied . Is there any other alternative for loading the .qm file Without using QApplication Object. ? i.e app in above example

Comment: I have to ask, do you try to debug result of load function. Is it true or false, further answers depends on this.